# sql query help in .Net MVC5

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

This seems so basic and I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Working with .net MVC5 I have a route /{categoryName}/ and I am trying to get all subcategories in a given {categoryName} to display.

Right now I have and am returning the subcategory id numbers:

```
var subCategoriesInCategory =
  from cat in db.Categories
  join subcat in db.SubCategories
  on cat.CategoryId equals subcat.CategoryId
  where (cat.CategoryName == categoryName)
  select (subcat);
```

I'm sure this is basic for someoone proficient in SQL, but ...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at this from the subcategory angle instead of the category.

```
var subCategoriesInCategory =
    from subcat in db.SubCategories
    where subcat.CategoryId == somevalue
    select subcat;
```

You would need to replace `somevalue` with the CategoryID value of the matching Category.

Or you could bypass the join clause by doing this:

```
var subCategoriesInCategory =
    from subcat in db.SubCategories
    where subcat.CategoryId == (from cat
        in db.Categories
        where cat.CategoryName == categoryName
        select cat.CategoryId
    ).FirstOrDefault()
    select subcat;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks OK.  Try a category you know has subcats

```
var subCategoriesInCategory =
  (from cat in db.Categories
  join subcat in db.SubCategories
  on cat.CategoryId equals subcat.CategoryId
  where (cat.CategoryName == "ExistingCategory")
  select subcat).FirstOrDefault();
if (subCategoriesInCategory == null ) 
{
   // somethings wrong !
}
```

or if you just want the subCategory IDs

```
 ...  select new { subcat.ID }
```